# Set Cookie in Javascript then window.location.href doesn't send updated coookie

Tags: javascript, session-cookies

I'm setting a cookie using jquery.cookie. I can verify after setting that it's available in javascript with $.cookie("somecookie").

However when I do a window.location.href = "/somerelativeurl" the updated cookie is not sent to the server. (only the old version is sent.)

Since my code will do a redirect if the cookie isn't updated properly, I can also see the redirect request, and it has the cookie on it properly updated and everything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably a path problem.

Try to set cookie as follow:

```
$.cookie("somecookie", 1, { path : "/" });
```

Comment: Very very odd issue. It appears that this is required only after the cookie has been cleared once. From then on, it doesn't get properly updated unless you put in the path....