# How to remove a cookie from a browser in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, jwt, token

I am trying to remove the token cookie from the browser when logging out but with my current code that doesn't seem to be working. Also the Cookie.get() function is returning an empty object when a cookie is still visible in the browser. I have tried looking at other solutions but nothing seem to be working.

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "../../history";
import Cookie from "js-cookie";

export default function Tool() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function logout() {
    localStorage.clear();
    Cookie.remove("token");
    console.log(Cookie.get(), "Oooooooooooooo");
    navigate("/login");
  }

  return (
    <div >
      <div className="topButtons">
        <button onClick={() => logout()}>LogOut</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Was the cookie set using js-cookie?

Comment: Nope it was set to the header through the back end

Comment: It's likely then that because the cookie wasn't set by the library you're using that it won't let you remove it. The library likely sets them using a specific format that way it can parse them in a specific way which let's it work.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275683/set-cookie-in-javascript-then-window-location-href-doesnt-send-updated-coookie) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing similar behavior and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275683/set-cookie-in-javascript-then-window-location-href-doesnt-send-updated-coookie), indicating it may be because of a bug that can be worked around by specifying the `path` in the cookie options parameter. This solved the issue for me.

With js-cookie you'd do it this way:

```
// set the cookie
Cookie.set('token', 'token.example.value', {path: '/'});

// remove the cookie
Cookie.remove('token', {path: '/'});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try remove all cookies first: `document.cookie = ''`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This didnt work

Answer (score -1):

Using the remove method from library

```js
Cookies.remove('name')
// Removing a nonexistent cookie neither raises any exception nor returns any value.
```

Comment: Already tried that but it didntn work